# Setting up NLog with an AspNetCore Api and debugging with Docker throws continual cannot find file errors

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm having some issues with NLog, .NET Core 2.2 AspNet Api project and debugging a Docker container in Visual Studio 2017.

I've followed the setup guide on the NLog Github site, added the code to the Program Main method, created an nlog.config file:

```
var logger = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
Debug.Write(logger);
try
{
    logger.Debug("init main");
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //NLog: catch setup errors
    logger.Error(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

The application runs incredibly slow, it takes an age to configure the logger. But it does eventually get the config file.

If I follow the Output whilst it's doing this, I get a continuous list of error messages as follows:

```
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/SharpGaming.Api.Gateway.Ui.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Runtime.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2/nlog/4.6.5/lib/netstandard2.0/NLog.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/netstandard.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2/nlog.web.aspnetcore/4.8.3/lib/netstandard2.0/NLog.Web.AspNetCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.5/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.5/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Step into: Stepping over property 'NLog.Config.ConfigurationItemFactory.get_Default'. To step into properties or operators, go to Tools->Options->Debugging and uncheck 'Step over properties and operators (Managed only)'.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Collections.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.ComponentModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Data.Common.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Net.Mail.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Net.Sockets.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Linq.Expressions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Linq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Private.Uri.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.IO.FileSystem.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Memory.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Buffers.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Threading.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2/nlog.extensions.logging/1.5.1/lib/netstandard2.0/NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Private.Xml.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Threading.Thread.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Collections.Specialized.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Drawing.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Threading.Timer.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.5/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

This goes on for several more Exceptions

```
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Console.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Loaded '/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/2.2.5/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

... and several more.
That's just it configuring the logger.

It continues to do this once the logger has loaded.

I figured that perhaps it was running in Debug, but the DockerFile had created a Release package. So I tried changing this so it ran as either Release or Debug, still does the same thing.

The deployed code to the docker instance doesn't include the PDB files, which I would expect.

It's almost like the NLog dll is trying to run in Debug, when it should be running in Release?

If I remove the setup code for NLog, everything works fine. I get no errors and the app runs smoothly and quickly in a docker container.

I'm using Windows for Docker and creating Linux Dockers.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out...

The nlog.config file was pointing to a Windows directory.

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    autoReload="true"
    internalLogLevel="DEBUG"
    internalLogFile="c:\log\apigateway\internal-nlog.txt"
    throwExceptions="true">
```

Removing these lines:

```
    internalLogLevel="DEBUG"
    internalLogFile="c:\log\apigateway\internal-nlog.txt"

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    autoReload="true"
    throwExceptions="true">
```

Stopped the errors being thrown.

I discovered this by opening the Exception Settings Window: Debug > Windows > Exception Settings. Going to the Common Language Runtime Exceptions section and checking the "System.IO.IOException" exception. So that it would throw on exception.

This gave me an "Invalid argument" exception, the stack trace:

```
at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
```

basically told me that there might be a problem with the directory?